# ArchUnit - methods provided by an object

Tags: java, unit-testing, archunit

I'd like assert public API methods provided by an object instance.

Pseudocode sample:

```java
Api api = Api.create();

assertThat(api)
  .hasPublicMethodNamed("foo")
  .doesNotHavePublicMethodNamed("bar");
```

Is it possible to accomplish this with ArchUnit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArchUnit rules are based on classes, but you can ask your `api` instance for its class (`api.getClass()`).

Full example for [JUnit4](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_junit_support) (for JUnit5, just drop the `ArchUnitRunner`):

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.AnalyzeClasses;
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest;
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchUnitRunner;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.methods;

@RunWith(ArchUnitRunner.class)
@AnalyzeClasses(packagesOf = SO76536531.class)
public class SO76536531 {
    @ArchTest
    ArchRule public_API_naming_conventions =
        methods()
            .that().areDeclaredIn(getApi().getClass())
            .and().arePublic()
            .should().haveName("foo")
            // .orShould().haveName("foo2") // to allow others names, too
            .andShould().notHaveName("bar"); // redundant; just for illustration

    Object getApi() {
        return new Api();
    }

    static class Api {
        public void foo() {
        }

        // public void foo2() {
        // }

        public void bar() {
        }
    }
}
```

(Note  that allowing for names `foo` and `foo2` in this way will not guarantee that your API has both methods. But your question didn't specify what you want to obtain. Feel free to clarify if needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ArchRule:

```
ArchRule rule = classes().should(havePublicMethod("foo")).and(haveNoPublicMethod("bar"));
rule.check(classes);
```

It checks that all classes have a public method named “foo” and do not have a public method named “bar”. You can also use the ArchUnitRunner for JUnit tests.